# Drupal 7 - Sending emails from localhost

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have Drupal 7.18 on my local machine. I've created a contact form on my site and I've also downloaded the SimpleNews module and created a "sign up for our newsletter" block.

I've tested both of these by filling out the contact form with my email and details and it says the form has been submitted. I've also done the same for the newsletter sign-up and it says "thank you for signing up to our newsletter".

However, these emails aren't getting through to my inbox. I've tried using a couple of different emails but still nothing.

Is it because I'm working locally on my machine? If not, what could be causing this?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are working locally. You need to configure an SMTP client to be able to send emails from a local machine.

Consider using [Mercury](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm) if you wanna be able to send emails from your local machine. it's free.